# Is it legal for the author of an open source project to remove history of contributors' commits?

Tags: gpl-3, contributor

I am new to open-source world. I have contributed some code to an open-source project licensed under GPLv3 but with no contributor agreement license.

Is it legal for the original author to upload the project somewhere else and delete the commit history of contributors (despite my code contribution still being there in the new uploaded project)?

Comment: In the code as it currently is, are your copyright statements preserved in your contributions?

Comment: @MadHatter: In the new uploaded project by the author my name and commits are not there

Comment: I repeat my specific question.  When you contributed code, you included copyright declarations of the form `(c) 2022 O. K. Validation`, yes?  And have those been preserved in the code?

Comment: @MadHatter: I didn't include copyright declarations of that form. I have just corrected a bug and submitted two pull requests and got merged.

Comment: Is your total contribution substantial? Minor and trivial bugfixes may not be worth the noise in the code.

Comment: @MadHatter, the OP isn't asking about copyright anything, just about his commits in the repository. I'm also new to this, so I'd like to know why the copyright is important to his question?

Comment: @ReversedEngineer the OP was worried about the removal of commit messages without accompanying removal of contributed code, which I thought meant (s)he was worried about concomitant loss of credit.  I pointed out that commit messages aren't the right way to claim credit in free software, but copyright messages are: not only are they traditional, they're protected by most free software licences.

Comment: @MadHatter Thank you! Makes sense to me now.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Nearly all free software licences require the preservation of existing copyright notices.  If the author of a piece of GPLv3 software accepted your modified version, then since this code had to be conveyed under the terms of GPLv3, the author is required to preserve your copyright notice.

Nearly no free software licences concern themselves with the minutiae of source-code control systems, so nearly none of them make any reference to "*commit messages*" or "*history*", nor are there any requirements to preserve the artefacts of a particular source-code control system.  This is unquestionably a good thing, since otherwise projects would be full of `foo.c,v` files we could never remove.

You should go back to the author, apologetically point out that GPLv3 s5a *required* you to add a copyright notice to the file(s) you modified (and in which you now have a copyright interest), and ask if you could add those in a separate pull request.  Strictly speaking, the author isn't obliged to accept them, but most people in free software understand that the copyright notice is the standard currency of acknowledgement - and that source-code control system artefacts aren't.

Comment: Don't most open source projects require contributors to assign copyright to the project maintainers, so that all the contributors aren't required to agree to everything that's done with the software in the future?

Comment: @Barmar some do (notably, FSF projects), but most don’t. Even among projects with contributor agreements, most of those are contributor licensing agreements, not copyright assignment agreements.

Comment: I think I was assuming that the FSF model was typical.

Comment: @StephenKitt: Many open-source licenses are intended to allow for the inclusion of derivative works within other derivative works that have compatible licenses.  If person X adapts code written by person Y for use within project Z, the license from person Y may allow X to sub-license any recipients to use the code under the same terms offered by Y with the original, but I can't see how Y would have any authority to sign over copyright on X's material.

Comment: @Barmar That's mostly done on larger projects, or projects sponsored by a company.  There's actually a lot of work required in creating, tracking, and maintaining those CLAs, and many independent, small-to-midsize projects don't have the resources for it.

Comment: @supercat this isn’t about what recipients of project X can do with project X’s code (which is governed by project X’s license, as you say). It’s about project X’s requirements for contributions to project X itself. See for example projects from the FSF, the ASF, Facebook, Google ... Many such projects require contributors to sign some agreement before they will accept patches. In such contexts, copyright assignment is possible (albeit complex in some jurisdictions), and the FSF is one example, [*e.g.* Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Copyright-Assignment.html).

Comment: @supercat in your example, if project Z requires copyright assignment, then person X can’t contribute person Y’s code to it without person Y’s involvement, since person X can’t assign person Y’s copyright on the code to project Z.

Comment: In the OP's case, even if they didn't include copyright declarations with their change, they still hold copyright in the project, it just becomes harder to prove, right? For example, even if only the original author's name appears in the copyright declaration of the project and the commits, the original author still can't legally change the license to a proprietary license like they would be able to if they had authored the whole project themselves, right? The fact that the OP didn't write their own copyright statement doesn't mean they forfeit copyright, right?

Comment: What is a `foo.c,v` file?

Comment: @Bergi it's an [RCS file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_Control_System), a 40-year-old system for tracking and crediting source changes - which is rather my point.  JoL, yes, they still hold copyright - the OP's question seemed to be about *credit* rather than copyright or re-licensing rights.  Everyone else, could I beg you stop having conversations in this comments field?

Comment: You are correct in that the versioning history is not under the purview of GPL, but your conclusion that GPLv3 `required [OP] to add a copyright notice to the file(s) [he] modified` is not what I am reading in section 5 of the GPLv3 at all. It speaks of "the work", which is the whole collection of files, not just that single file. Having to mention every single author in every single modified file would be... a humongous waste of time and space. A top-level CONTRIBUTORS file or something like that may be just fine, and I'm sure that's a better place for OP to put his name if he is so inclined.

Comment: @AnoE if a `CONTRIBUTORS` file already exists in the codebase, then I'd agree that would be one possible place to put the notice.  I note, however, that the GPL itself advises anyone adding copyright notices "*to attach them to the start of each source file*", so while it may not be a requirement, it *is* best practice - and at about 50 (highly-compressible) bytes I don't think you can fairly describe it as a "*humongous waste of ... space*".

Comment: Maybe not in this case, but imagine every single committer adding his name and mail address to every single source file in every single open source project. ...

Comment: @AnoE who said anything about mailing addresses?  And your name should only be added to those file(s) which you have touched.  Do by all means object to what I'm saying, but it's not helpful to object to things that haven't been said!

Comment: @MadHatter, I did not try to put words in your mouth, but was elaborating why the factual statement you make in your accepted answer (GPLv3 somehow _requiring_ someone to add a copyright notice to the files they are modifying) is not only not part of GPLv3 when reading the actual formulation there, but why it often would not even be wise to do so. The answer is accepted, so it doesn't matter anymore I guess. I'd hate if people casually reading this in the future then think doing it that way really is part of the GPLv3, there's enough confusion out there as it is, anyways...